# Only execute first key press of 'hjkl' keys in VSCode VIM

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm using this [VIM Extension for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim). I want to limit my usage of 'hjkl' keys for better navigation habits. Some kind of timeout or something. Only first press should be counted - any extra presses should be discarded. Is it possible to configure this behavior in VSCode's VIM extension?

I found [VIM hardtime](https://github.com/takac/vim-hardtime) but don't think it's possible to integrate this easily in VSCode.

Comment: Or, you know, you could simply *decide* to not use `hjkl` when there are better motions.

Comment: @romainl It is easy to fall back to lazy habits without noticing. Besides, I'm asking a question about technical feasibility of this configuration.